# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 1, position 2

Tags: json.net, exe

I have a json string which is constructed by the following code:

```
string path1 = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IMAGE\\model\\net.mat";
string path2 = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IMAGE\\png\\Lab.png";
string path3 = "D:\\temp\\";
string[] strs={path1 ,path2 ,path3};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strs);
Console.WriteLine(json);

List<string> paths = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
Console.WriteLine(paths.Count);
```

and there is no error when I serialize it or deserialize it.
The **json** string is as follows:

```
 "[\"C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\IMAGE\\\\model\\\\net.mat\",\"C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\IMAGE\\\\png\\\\Lab.png\",\"D:\\\\temp\\\\\"]"
```

Then I pass the string **JSON** to a *.exe file and deserialize it.
The string the exe received  is as follow,which has changed after pass:

```
string json="[C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\IMAGE\\\\model\\\\net.mat,C:\\\\Program Files 
    (x86)\\\\IMAGE\\\\png\\\\Lab.png,D:\\\\temp\\]"；
```

Then when I use the follow code to deserialize it,error appear.The code is as follow:

```
List<string> paths = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
```

The error is:

> Unhandled JsonReaderException:Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 1, position 2.

I wonder why this is the case. Thanks.

Comment: `[C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IMAGEDL\\model\\net-e-100.mat,C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IMAGEDL\\Labelpng\\Lab.png,D:\\temp\]` is not well-formed JSON.  The strings needs to be surrounded by `"` characters.  Try uploading it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get `Error: Parse error on line 1:`.    Valid JSON would look like `["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IMAGEDL\\model\\net-e-100.mat", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IMAGEDL\\Labelpng\\Lab.png", "D:\\temp"]`.  If this is not a typo in your question and your JSON really does not have double-quote delimiters around your strings, that explains your problem.

Comment: Incidentally, your `string json = "...` c# code does not compile, since c# string literals cannot contain newlines.  So can you please confirm that your question really does include the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: How are you passing the JSON string to your EXE?

Comment: @BrianRogers I use the follow code to pass the JSON string to EXE: 
                    string[]pathArr={modelPath, labelPath, resultPath};// construct a string array
                    string paths = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pathArr);//convert to a JSON string                                                       
             Process pro = new Process();//then pass it to a exe
             pro.StartInfo.FileName = fullFileName;
             pro.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}", paths);

Comment: Does it have to be JSON you are passing to the EXE?  If the only thing in the JSON is an array of three paths, could you just pass these as three separate command line arguments instead?

Comment: @BrianRogers As pass the three paths, there are always apperar errors, I have to  convert them into a json string.The error is like:when i pass three paths para, the string[] args in the exe has more than 3 items.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put single quotes around the paths.

string json = "[ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IMAGEDL\\model\\net-e-100.mat',C:\\Program Files(x86)\\IMAGEDL\\Labelpng\\Lab.png, D:\\temp\\ ]";

Comment: Thanks for your help. This problem appear when I pass the json string to a execuable file(*.exe). When  I use it in a single program file,there is no problem. I changed my question to avoid misunderstanding.Thanks again.